# Regex for matching specific characters with spaces in between and before and after

Tags: java, regex

So I have been searching the internet for 4+ hours on clues of how to do this but I cannot find a way to do all I want.
What I want is to input this (for example):

```
  word1 !  ?? word2 word3 ..   .. word4, word5, word6 !?. word7 !! !
word8 word9 ?
. word10
```

And then match `.`, `!` and `?` in any order and any whitespace in between so that it returns me:

```
["word1", "word2 word3", "word4, word5, word6", "word7", "word8 word9", "word10"]
```

It might be worth mentioning I want to use `String.split()` for this purpose, but any other more efficient/easy way would very welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way

```
String data="word1 !  ?? word2 word3 ..   .. word4, word5, word6 !?. word7 !! !" +
        "word8 word9 ?" +
        ". word10";
for (String s:data.split("\\s*([!?.]+\\s*)+")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output

```
word1
word2 word3
word4, word5, word6
word7
word8 word9
word10
```

Comment: Your regex intrigues me though. I can't stop wondering how `([!?.]+\\s*)+` might not as well just take any-whitespace-and-have-it-happen-once-or-more and along with the first part ..... (lighbulb moment)... GENIUS! Thanks again. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    String s = "word1 !  ?? word2 word3 ..   .. word4, word5, word6 !?. word7 !! ! \n word8 word9 ?\n. word10";
    String[] a = s.split("(\\s*[!?.\n\r]+\\s*)+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output

```
[word1, word2 word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8 word9, word10]
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString(a)` is not perfect way to show content of array that elements also can have comas inside. Anyway +1 for correct split even if it is not that visible :).

Comment: @Pshemo Semi-correct. I didn't include it (sorry!), but I was also considering having any whitespace in between words (for example new line breaks) and not having those matched. So for example
`wordn (newline)
wordm`
would be a single string. Which this regex doesn't do :/

Comment: @Yokhen It wasn't that obvious. In example you showed in question new line was also place where split happen so this answer included \n and \r. Anyway if we remove them from regex you will get almost the same regex that I used.